# Customize the UIPickerView bar Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm wanting to change the appearance of the bar on the picker view, and I have no idea where I would go about doing this? I would like to make it look like it does in the image. [image]

Thank you in advance, all help is appreciated

Comment: You should give it a try first. If you google the same question you will get to know that this method `func pickerView(UIPickerView, viewForRow: Int, forComponent: Int, reusing: UIView?) -> UIView` is what you need to achieve this. Once you make a try, share your code if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hardcode your background to something like:
   [image]
2. Set your font when selected value changes

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       for index in 0 ..< self.pickerView(pickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent: component) {
           if index != row {
               // reset to unselected font for this index here
               // ...
           } else {
               // apply the selected font for this index here
               // ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

For customizing the font, you may need to use `pickerView(UIPickerView, viewForRow: Int, forComponent: Int, reusing: UIView?)` as noted by Kamran.

Comment: Thank you I will finish the functionality of the picker, and then work on the aesthetics and come back to you how that goes